# How to Add or Fill DataTable Image Column to DataGridView Image Column in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, image, datatable, datagridview, binding

I want to ask if there is anything wrong with my code, and how can I fill datatable to DataGridView with this data properly.

Thanks

```
  Private Sub LoadData()
        Dim item As New List(Of item())
        Grid.Bind(item)
    End Sub
 Private Sub FillDataTable(Avatar As Image, iRow As Integer, ByVal Codeproduct As String)
        Dim row As DataRow = _myTable.NewRow()
        row("") = Avatar
        row("No") = iRow
        row("Codeproduct") = Codeproduct
        _myTable.Rows.Add(row)
    End Sub
    Private Sub AddColumnsProgrammatically()
        Dim Col1 = New DataGridViewImageColumn()
        Dim Col2 = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        Dim Col3 = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        Col2.HeaderText = ""
        Col2.Name = "Column1"
        Col2.DataPropertyName = "{GetAvatar()}"
        Col2.HeaderText = "No"
        Col2.Name = "Column2"
        Col2.DataPropertyName = "No"
        Col3.HeaderText = "CodeProduct"
        Col3.Name = "Column3"
        Col3.DataPropertyName = "CodeProduct"
        Grid.Columns.AddRange(New DataGridViewColumn() {Col1, Col2, Col3})
    End Sub
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        AddColumnsProgrammatically()
        _myTable.Columns.Add("", GetType(Image()))
        _myTable.Columns.Add("No", GetType(Integer))
        _myTable.Columns.Add("Codeproduct", GetType(String))
        LoadData()
    End Sub
  Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress

        If e.KeyChar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(Keys.Enter) Then
            Dim iRow As Integer
            If Grid.RowCount - 1 = 0 Then
                iRow = 1
            Else
                iRow = Convert.ToInt32(Grid.Rows(Grid.RowCount - 2).Cells(1).Value.ToString()) + 1
            End If
            FillDataTable(avatar, iRow, TextBox1.Text)
            Grid.DataSource = _myTable
            TextBox1.Clear()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
End Class
Public Class item
    Public Property No() As Integer
    Public Property CodeProduct() As String
    Public Function GetAvatar() As DataGridViewAvatar
        Return New DataGridViewAvatar() With {
        .Value = CType(Me.CodeProduct, String),
        .Icon = Image.FromFile("money.png")
    }
    End Function
End Class
```

[image: result datagridview column image]

Comment: It seems that this code has been written by an AI because it's nonsensical. You're going to need to perform some research without the AI and create your own code - it's not clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Tudeschizieuinchid , Thank you for your reply `It seems that this code has been written by an AI because it's nonsensical. ` You mean "Al" . I'm using KimToo's NuGet Library Binding Provider (DataGridView).  `FillDataTable(avatar, iRow, TextBox1.Text)` `'Avatar' is not declared` actually the problem is in the fillDataTable method

Comment: If you're using a library, that information should be included in your OP.  I couldn't find any documentation for the library that you mentioned. You may consider alternatives. The following may be of interest: [Ways to Bind DataGridView in C# Windows Forms](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deveshomar/ways-to-bind-datagridview-in-window-forms-C-Sharp/).

Answer (score 1):

Here's [a link](https://kimtoo.gitbook.io/dgv-framework/data-binding/binding-ienumerable-less-than-t-greater-than)!
from the documentation link I got the solution

```
    itemtransfer.Add(New ItemTransfer With {
                            .No = iRow,
                           .CodeProduct = BtxtBarcode.Text
                            })
                        grid.Bind(itemtransfer)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).